# Python check earlier of two string dates

Tags: python, string, date

Suppose I have two dates represented by strings. `MM-DD-YY`

What's the most efficient way to find out which date comes first in Python? I tried the following approach, but it quickly got messy!

I'm looking for the following output : `return 1 if first date comes before, 0 if second date comes before, -1 if dates are exactly the same`

Hopefully someone has a cleaner approach

```
date1 = "02-20-10"
date2 = "03-21-09"

def firstDateBefore(date1, date2):      
    month1, day1, year1 = date1.split("-")
    month2, day2, year2 = date2.split("-")

    month1 = int(month1)
    month2 = int(month2)
    day1 = int(day1)
    day2 = int(day2)
    year1 = int(year1)
    year2 = int(year2) 

    if (year1 < 13 && year2 < 13):      #both in the year 2000's
        if (year1 < year2):
            return 1
        else if (year1 > year2):
            return 0;
        else:               #years are equal
            if (month1 < month2):   
                return 1
            else if (month1 > month2):
                return 0
            else:           #months are equal
                if (day1 < day2):
                    return 1
                else if (day1 > day2):
                    return 0
                else 
                    return -1   # the Dates are exactly the same!
```

Comment: Also, I realize I have to cast the strings as integers after I do a split by "-"

Comment: "return 1 if first date comes before, 0 if second date comes before, -1 if dates are exactly the same" sounds weird. Normally, the last two are swapped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Python comes with batteries included](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime).

```
from datetime import datetime

d1 = datetime.strptime(date1, "%m-%d-%y")
d2 = datetime.strptime(date2, "%m-%d-%y")

assert d1 > d2
```

[What `"%m-%d-%y"` means.](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)

Comment: +1.  Only gripe I have is removing the namespace datetime by importing strptime directly.  "Namespaces are one honking great idea -- let's do more of those!"

Comment: @sberry Yes, [PEP-20](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) should be our first guide.

Answer (score 0):

You could translate date to timestamp to quick compare :

```
from datetime import datetime

def firstDateBefore(date1, date2):
    d1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(date1, '%m-%d-%y').strftime('%s')
    d2 = datetime.datetime.strptime(date2, '%m-%d-%y').strftime('%s')
    if d1 > d2:
        return d1
    elif d1 == d2:
        return 'same date'
    else:
        return D2
```

This exemple return the greater date or 'same date' if date are equal...